# An inequality involving operator and trace norms

Tags: matrices, inequality, operator-theory

Consider two square matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and let $\| \cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|$ be, respectively, the trace norm (the sum of singular values) and the usual operator norm (the maximum of singular values).

Is there a known bound for the following quantity?
$$
\sup\{\alpha > 0: \; \alpha \, \text{tr}(A^TB) \le \| A+B\|_1, \, \forall B \; \text{s.t.} \;\|B\| \le 1\}
$$

EDIT: Assume $A \neq 0$.

Comment: If you're asking generally, then there is no supremum for $A = 0$.

Comment: Assume that the smallest singular value of $A$ is bounded away from zero.

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136005/an-inequality-involving-operator-and-trace-norms) on MO.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/136005/21564). I have replicated the accepted answer by Skoro below.

> Since I cant comment, I will leave this thought here. Since $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||$ (as you defined them) are dual norms, it must be that tr$((A+B)^TX)\leq||A+B||_1$ for any $X$ such that $||X||\leq 1$. Therefore, tr$(A^TB)\leq ||A+B||_1 - ||B||^2<||A+B||_1$ (since tr$(B^TB)\geq||B||^2$).